# apex: Innerclass not not available in map in outside class

Tags: apex, class, inner-class

I have the following setup:

```
public with sharing class MyOuterClass extends BaseClass {

  public class MyInnerClass {
    public Id classId {get; private set;}

    public MyInnerClass() {}
    public MyInnerClass(Id classId) {
      this.classId = classId;
    }
  }
}
```

Then in an different class entirely I have this method:

```
public static Map<Id, MyOuterClass.MyInnerclass> getStuff(){
  Map<Id, MyOuterClass.MyInnerclass> results = new Map<Id, MyOuterClass.MyInnerclass>();

  return results;
}
```

In the last class there I get InvalidType errors in the Map definitions. It says `Invalid type: MyOuterClass.MyInnerclass`

Everything I can find says this is the proper use of an inner class. What am I missing?

Comment: You've got something else going on here, your code, as is (with the removal of `extends BaseClass`) compiles just fine. If you remove the base class extension statement, does your code compile?

Comment: Yeah this seems like a case of a failed save of `MyOuterClass`.

Comment: Thanks guys. It was an issue of the two classes each not saving properly because they were dependent on each other. I was able to get them saved properly and now it works. So, no actual issues in the code.

Comment: Might as well add it as an answer so others can benefit from your learning experience. (And please don't forget to accept your answer in a couple days when finally able.)

Comment: Happy to let you take the credit. If you add the answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Almost certainly you get this failure because `MyOuterClass` failed to save. Depending on your IDE, you may think it compiled when there is really an error. Make sure you get `MyOuterClass` to compile first, then your second class will be able to reference the `MyOuterClass.MyInnerClass` type.